# Group by 2 columns and count

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySql table - user_actions:
id - int
user_id - int
timestamp - datetime
action - int

a data example:

```
1|5|01.01.2011 21:00:00|1
2|5|01.01.2011 21:00:00|3
3|6|01.01.2011 21:00:00|5
3|6|01.02.2011 21:00:00|5
```

I want to count the number of users who made an action in each day (no matter how many actions), in the above example the output should be:

```
01.01.2011|2 
01.02.2011|1
```

- meaning 2 users made actions in 01.01.2011 and one user in 01.02.2011

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id)
     , DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') 
  from table 
 group by DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: not good... I am getting 2 rows for the first date (01.01.2011) instead of one

Comment: I've updated query. I wrongly understood your question. I hope that now it's correct.